# What's the best way to use pipeline between http request and responses

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, stream, transform

I like use streams, but faced with the following problem.

For example, we have simple `pipeline` of several piped streams

```
var pipeline = new stream.Transform({ objectMode: true, highWatermark: 1 });

pipeline.on('pipe', function(source) {
    source.unpipe(this);
    source.pipe(stream1).pipe(stream2). ... .pipe(this);
}
```

And, **ideally**, need to pass all http data through that `pipeline`

```
http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    request.pipe(pipeline).pipe(response);
});
```

But we know that `request` and `response` streams need to `end` after every request and will `end` our `pipeline` (cause they are piped together).

We can create new `pipeline` for every request (like in [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20662675/1690354)).

But I don't believe that it is a right way to recreating so often and so much complex streams.

Alternative way is to reusing our `pipeline` for every request

```
http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    request.on('data', function() {
        pipeline.write(data);
    });
    pipeline.on('data', function(data) {
        response.end(data);
    });
});
```

But here I have another problems:

All requests will pass through one stream and we will loose all beaty of nodejs asynchrony (maybe I am wrong)

Difficult to keep link between `request` and corresponding `response` streams.

Is there some good way to realise it **only by using streams**?

Comment: Check out the `request` npm library. It lets you pipe requests and responses. https://github.com/request/request#streaming

Comment: Thanks! I used this library many times for outgoing requests. But forgot that it can also pipe request and responces. I will inspect their souces to know how they prefer to do it!